# Getting Some errors from Retina.js, While web page loaded on high end PC

Tags: jquery, retina

Am a beginner in JQuery, while testing my web application on high-end PC (specifically say when using windows 10 setting `scale and layout>change the size of text apps and other items` to 150% ) '**retina.min.js**' showing some errors from following functions

Function 1

```
function r(e, t) {
    try {
        this.path = e;
        if (typeof t !== "undefined" && t !== null) {
            this.at_2x_path = t;
            this.perform_check = false
        } else {
            this.at_2x_path = e.replace(/\.\w+$/, function (e) {
                return "@2x" + e
            });
            this.perform_check = true
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        alert("Function 1" + err.message);
    }
}
```

> > error: Function 1: Cannot read property 'replace' of null

Function 2

```
r.prototype.check_2x_variant = function (e) {
    try {
        var n, i = this;
        if (this.is_external()) {
            return e(false)
        } else if (!this.perform_check && typeof this.at_2x_path !== 
"undefined" && this.at_2x_path !== null) {
            return e(true)
        } else if (this.at_2x_path in r.confirmed_paths) {
            return e(true)
        } else {
            n = new XMLHttpRequest;
            n.open("HEAD", this.at_2x_path);
            n.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (n.readyState != 4) {
                    return e(false)
                }
                if (n.status >= 200 && n.status <= 399) {
                    if (t.check_mime_type) {
                        var s = n.getResponseHeader("Content-Type");
                        if (s == null || !s.match(/^image/i)) {
                            return e(false)
                        }
                    }
                    r.confirmed_paths.push(i.at_2x_path);
                    return e(true)
                } else {
                    return e(false)
                }
            };
            n.send()
        }
    } catch (err) {
        alert("Function 5 :" + err.message);
    }
};
```

> > error: Function 5: Cannot read property 'match' of null

Error Msg on browser Console

```
retina.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null
at new r (retina.min.js:1)
at new i (retina.min.js:1)
at t.onload (retina.min.js:1)
r @ retina.min.js:1
i @ retina.min.js:1
t.onload @ retina.min.js:1
load (async)
n.init @ retina.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ retina.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ retina.min.js:1
```

why is this happning ?

Its a plug in and i have no idea how it is working , so i dont wanna mess it up . Please help me .. what should i change ?

Comment: when you inspect on chrome check your "e" value. It may happen that your images definition may be wrong. Please edit your question and put your img html